# Firebase Remote Config error 8003, Unity, iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

We have a game in Unity 5.6.1f that uses Firebase Remote Config. Everything works fine on our devices, but after release we are noticing a lot of errors sent from player devices to our error reporting system. Problem occurs only on iOS.

`Remote Config: Fetch encountered an error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.remoteconfig.ErrorDomain error 8003.)`

I can't find a solution anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FirebaseRemoteConfig/2.0.1/Constants/FIRRemoteConfigError.html) the error `8003` is defined as

`FIRRemoteConfigErrorInternalError = 8003`

So the issue is probably not on your side.

*Added this so it might help someone in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

Like @jd291 said, `8003` documentation seems to point to backend problem:

```swift
/// Internal error that covers all internal HTTP errors.
FIRRemoteConfigErrorInternalError = 8003,
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs if you haven't published your configs on firebase yet.